# How to trigger build in jenkins through command in HipChat

Tags: jenkins, hipchat, chatops

I need to trigger build in jenkins which is in cloud (AZURE) by a command passed in HipChat Integration.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

The thing that you are looking for is often referred to as *ChatOps*. There are couple of tools that allow you to do such thing, which is effectively a program joining the chat room (the "bot") and waiting for commands.

The list of tools includes [Hubot](https://github.com/hipchat/hubot-hipchat) and [StackStorm](https://stackstorm.com/), which then call Jenkins API to trigger the job. An adapter for StackStorm exists [here](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2contrib/tree/master/packs/jenkins).